# Vs code blank terminal problem, can't enter anything

Tags: visual-studio-code, ubuntu-18.04

I'm user using Visual Studio code. 
A few days ago, I've gone through some problems.
It's about "blank terminal". I'm not sure what trigger this problem.
I guess it's related with vs code updated 1.39 version. I attached the picture below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBAvQ.png)
I've tried searching solution in order to solve this problem. but I failed.
1. remove the 1.39 version. and re install vscode. (remove vscode file)
 - sudo apt remove vscode, sudo apt autoremove 
 - I searched .vscode and then remove all( some setting file left.) 
2. I tried to install vscode by snap, but result was same.
3. I started with root
 - sudo code --user-data-dir => teminal is possible to see but environments not working => fail
4. I tried down grade.
 - version 38,37 => failed (it's same result)
 - version 32 => success (but it's old version, limited several utilities)

**Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS , 64 bit
Anyone having same problems and  working out, Please tell some methods. 
I look forward to getting reply. Thanks.

Comment: This isn't helpful for solving the issue, but I am having the same issue. I am running 1.39.2 on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS 64 bit also.

Comment: @JaRay 
https://superuser.com/questions/1113022/how-do-i-remove-vs-code-settings-from-ubuntu
it works Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running into this issue with vscode that was installed through the ubuntu software center

I uninstalled it and deleted any settings using this https://superuser.com/questions/1113022/how-do-i-remove-vs-code-settings-from-ubuntu

I then installed through anaconda since I was already using it.  This install worked fine.

Comment: It works for me, I think some setting files trigger problems. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5):

Setting `"terminal.integrated.inheritEnv"` to `true` in settings.json solved this problem for me.

I think it is related to [this bug](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/76542)

Comment: I had this problem and this help me. The settings.json can be searched by going to File->preference->settings. In the bar search for it.

Comment: Time files, some upgraded, Problem solved. I think it's related with version problem. I tried after! Thanks all reply.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select a default shell. Where it says `1:`, click the down arrow and select your shell.

Comment: That does not help in my case.  There are 4 options and none of them make a difference.